# Validation of viewstate MAC failed error.

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate, auto-generate, machinekey

I built a website with some ASPX-C# pages, I added a new page with a form. The problem is that when I click submit I get the following error:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same
>   validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in
>   a cluster.

The forms in all the other pages work fine, but after the submit in this specific page - the forms don't work and I get this error for all the forms. I tried to search for a solution online, but it seems that the solutions I found didn't work. :(

**Update**
I put this code in the web config page AND the problem solved :

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false" />
```

**But** the PostBack command is not working well now.

My question is WHY and how can I fix it?

Please help me I have to solve this as quick as possible.

Comment: what are the soulutions u tried??

Comment: Update the question, pleas review it

Comment: Do you have any script in that page that changes the contents of the controls (dropdownlists, etc.) before the submit?

Comment: I think so, I have this :
 <%this.Form.Action = "ViewArticle.aspx?ArticleID=" + TrackID; %>
But I have the same code in other page and there are not problem there

Comment: Can you pleas help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters add this on you `web.config` and check if its working:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="A4B12CCDD50E95F8GB9GFH6JKAT4Y0U0I2OF2DF2AAFE5AB46189C,IsolateApps" 
            validation="AES" 
            validationKey="480CDF2AS9S9AS5CFDGF0GHFH9JJH4KHKAKLJ2L9F3SAS82A6C16911A29EF48903783F94529C21570AACB72766FB38CD4CE7B85B0ACE3149DC5FC1CCF1AA1CECE3579659996593B06,IsolateApps"/>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647525/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed) for more details

Comment: Thank you, it works BUT now when I "PostBack" (after first submit) it didn't work, only after the first post back it work, why? and how can I make the "PostBack " work on the first time?

Comment: Can you pleas help me with this problem?

Comment: remove this `enableViewStateMac="false"`