# ASP.NET Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: asp.net

I've a listView to show list of data. It was all good and suddendly we are receiving the error message below:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If
>   this application is hosted by a Web
>   Farm or cluster, ensure that
>   configuration specifies the same
>   validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster.Invalid viewstate. Client
>   IP...User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; InfoPath.3) ViewState:

Could anyone please guide me through how to fix this issue. Please note:
1. Our IIS Server is standalone not a farmed.

Update:
The ListView has hyperlink to records where uses can click.
Thanks heaps.

Comment: Just encountered this error in testing, when setting the client to disallow accepting cookies, and trying to login to an app. Rather bizarre circumstance. Same behavior on my (win7) localhost and a win2008 server.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It could be that IIS recycled your app and therefore you get new keys for the session/view state. To alleviate this, add a machine static key in the web.config.

Generate a key from  http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/GenerateMachineKey/GenerateMachineKey.aspx

And place the keys in your web.config example as below

```
<machineKey
validationKey="56AB7132992003EE87F74AE4D9675D65EED8018D3528C0B8874905B51940DEAF6B85F1D922D19AB8F69781B2326A2F978A064708822FD8C54ED74CADF8592E17"
decryptionKey="A69D80B92A16DFE1698DFE86D4CED630FA56D7C1661C8D05744449889B88E8DC"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

The `<machineKey>` should be put inside `<system.web>` section.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is `Different keys across postback`,so you need to generate new encryption keys.

From Code Project:

> There are two keys that ASP.NET uses
>   to encrypt, decrypt, and validate data
>   in ViewState, Forms Authetication
>   tickets, and out-of-process Session
>   data. The decryptionKey is used for
>   encryption and decryption of
>   authentication tickets and encrypted
>   ViewState information. The
>   validationKey is used to validate
>   ViewState and ensure it hasn't been
>   tampered with, and generate unique
>   application-specific session IDs for
>   out-of-process session storage.
>   You can run into problems if the key changes between postbacks.

---

A good article how to do this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/machineKey.aspx), [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312906), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418233/setting-viewstateuserkey-gives-me-a-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error) and [here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey).

In general you need to take some issues in consideration when moving to the production environment.

A good article about this [here](http://daptivate.com/archive/2008/02/12/top-10-best-practices-for-production-asp-net-applications.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the specifics of your app, one way that this can happen if the page is submitted before it is fully loaded.  You can work around by using javascript to prevent postbacks/submissions prior to the page being fully loaded.  Also try to reduce the size of the page if possible.  Disable the viewstate for any controls that you don't use it.

Comment: The ListView has hyperlink to records where uses can click.

Comment: could Mozilla browser be causing this issue??

Answer (score 0):

This may occur on the other scenario when the Pool recycling happen before the Sql command execution complete, When your application dealing with large amount of data processing (such kind of report generation  ..etc ) .Check the Application pool of your application and increase the recycling interval.

Answer (score -2):

THis could possibly help you:

```
<%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="false" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>
```

Note: `EnableViewStateMac="false"`

Comment: Could you explain in what it help?

Comment: Should not do this. If you make it false, ASP.NET will stop checking if the ViewState has been tampered with. This is like inviting hackers to hack your application.

Comment: If your security system is giving you false alarms is the correct solution to **fix the security system** or **turn it off and hope for the best**?

Comment: I just have to reiterate:  don't ever do this.