# asp.net - User is redirected to login page after succesfull login in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, authentication

I have a problem with login page in a new Web forms template (VS2012). I described background of the problem here: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265692/disabling-anti-xsrf-token-validation-in-asp-net-web-forms-redirects-to-login-pag). Now, login is succesfull in Chrome and FF, but also in IE, because LoggedIn event of Login control is fired, however in IE, the user is redirected to login page again ? This is the case only on IIS 7, locally it works on IIS Express.

Comment: Have you enabled cookies in IE ?

Comment: Yep, cookies are enabled. We tried on IE 9 (Win7), IE 10 (Win7) and IE 11 (Win8), and it is the same.

Comment: I found what is the problem...we have a picture in our SiteMaster, url('~/Images/Logo.png'). When our site is called as: http://app_server/myapp, then it says that this file is not found! Hoewever when the site is called as: http://192.168.80.4/myapp, then it works. What is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like a bug, where your return url is substituted with the login page which is delivered when you request /Images/logo.png before you log in. You'll need to excempt /Images/logo.png from forms authentication, or check if you have a bug (like missing quotes) in your markup.

Comment: Actually it is not a problem with image, at all. When I call app like: http://app_server/myapp it doesn't work and redirect to login page, but when I call it like this: http://192.168.80.4/myapp then it works. What's the problem here ?

Comment: It seems that my problem is related to this: http://serverfault.com/questions/161221/cannot-get-iis7-to-send-cookies-to-ie. How to fix this without changing computer name ?