# Asp.Net webforms Viewstate validation getting failed

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, state-management

I have a website hosted on shared server, running on .Net version : 4.0.30319.34280

I was initially getting the following error

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

In order to fix it I added a  section in my web.config, by following the steps mentioned at : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312906

Now I am getting the following error

Unable to validate data.

stack trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to validate data.]
   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData) +1072
   System.Web.UI.Page.EncryptString(String s, Purpose purpose) +150
   System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.FormatWebResourceUrl(String assemblyName, String resourceName, Int64 assemblyDate, Boolean htmlEncoded) +52
   System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrlInternal(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, Boolean htmlEncoded, Boolean forSubstitution, IScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean enableCdn) +662
   System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrl(Type type, String resourceName, Boolean htmlEncoded, IScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean enableCdn) +188
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.GetWebResourceUrl(Page owner, Type type, String resourceName, Boolean htmlEncoded, IScriptManager scriptManager, Boolean enableCdn) +99
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(Type type, String resourceName) +96
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterValidatorCommonScript() +212
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +85
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

Any help in solving would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that IIS recycled your app and therefore you get new keys for the session/view state. To alleviate this, add a machine static key in the web.config.

```
<machineKey
validationKey="56AB7132992003EE87F74AE4D9675D65EED8018D3528C0B8874905B51940DEAF6B85F1D922D19AB8F69781B2326A2F978A064708822FD8C54ED74CADF8592E17"
decryptionKey="A69D80B92A16DFE1698DFE86D4CED630FA56D7C1661C8D05744449889B88E8DC"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

[Refrence Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259844/asp-net-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed)

Comment: I already added that.
Error am getting right now is "Unable to validate data", after adding machinekey section.