# Validation of viewstate MAC failed after form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

So I have this error on ONE computer (not on the two others) :

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, [...]
```

It is happenning on a dev computer, so everithing runs on the computer, the assertion "If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster" is **FALSE**

According to the MSDN blog I should remove the action attribute of my form (in `ask_full_report.aspx`)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="full_report.aspx">
```

But I don't want to remove the action attribute, I want to submit my form to `full_report.aspx`.

Here is my Web.config (I removed some keys under appSettings)

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="URL_BASE" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

For [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827214/3484498) : I don't use `ViewStateUserKey`

Do you have any ideas of what is going on please ?

**Note** : I don't think it is a duplicate of

- [Setting ViewStateUserKey gives me a "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418233/setting-viewstateuserkey-gives-me-a-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error)
- [Validation of viewstate MAC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647525/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed) [Duplicate]

Extra ressource : [MSDN - HttpException Due to Invalid Viewstate After Installing .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/05/13/viewstate-exception-may-come-with-action-attribute-in-form-tag-post-net-framework-3-5-sp1.aspx)

---

EDIT: Today, without any action taken, I don't have the error anymore. I have left this post open because this error is not well documented. If anyone has a solution, post an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same problem and the solution was to put the following code in the web.config inside `<system.web>` like following

```
<system.web>
<machineKey validationKey="627BF72BB33AA8D28CA2C3E80920BA4DF0B726F97EEFBB0F4818350D63E6AFA380811F13ED1F086E386284654DB3"
decryptionKey="F40B6E5A02B29A181D2D213B5ED8F50B73CFCFD0CC56E137" validation="SHA1" />
    </system.web>
```

see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx)  to generate your own key if you want

Comment: Any idea on why other computers doesn't need it ?

Comment: Today, without any action taken, I don't have the error anymore. (...)